# I3 wm: application icon on all monitors

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, i3-window-manager

Some applications such as skype, audacious place an icon on status bar, but it is only displayed on 1 of my monitors, how do make it shown on both of them?
I am using Mint XFCE4 with I3 window manager.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with *i3* as *i3* uses (only) [*xembed*](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-latest.html) to implement tray icons, which does not allow for multiple icons of the same application.

There is also a newer specification ([Status Notifier](http://www.notmart.org/misc/statusnotifieritem/index.html)) that allows for multiple icons, but it is not part of *i3* and even then it would depend on support from the actual application to use it.